Multi-Signature Wallets
In a 2-of-3 multisig wallet , what if 2 persons team up to extract all the fund themselves and thereby betraying the 3rd person, Is there any way to avoid such situations for this specific multi-sig? And if not, why would anyone trust the others parties to be honest in a decentralized system ?

The purpose of a multi-signature wallet is to provide flexibility.
If you want every single owner to agree on every transaction, you create an n-of-n wallet. If you want to be able to vote with fewer people than there are owners, you create an m-of-n wallet.
You should only create a 2-of-3 multi-signature wallet if you're fine with the other two owners being able to execute transactions without your consent. If you're not fine with that, create a 3-of-3 wallet.

If I were to create a 3-of-3 wallet, then where is the  flexibility , and moreover, the so called claim of multi-sig wallet to avoid single point of failure is then meaningless if anyone's key get's stolen/lost for a 3-3 wallet.

The flexibility is in the possibility to create any number of owners and any required number of signers. If you want to avoid a single point of failure, create a 2-of-3 wallet. You said above "what if 2 persons team up". Well, 2 persons are the majority here and it seems like you want to have a full control as the minority. The entire blockchain and the entire world works on the principle of majority.
